# Как трансформировать получаемые данные?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, laravel

```
products
--- id
--- name

attributes
--- id
--- name

attribute_values
--- id
--- attribute_id
--- name

attribute_value_product
--- id
--- attribute_value_id
--- product_id
```

**Products**

- Продукту может принадлежать много Значений.

**Attributes**

- Атрибуту может принадлежать много Значений.

**Attribute Values**

- Значению может принадлежать один Атрибут.
- Значению может принадлежать много Продуктов.

Как я получаю эти данные во View.

```php
foreach ($products as $product) {
    foreach ($product->attributeValues as $value) {
        $value->attribute->name
        $value->name
    }
}
```

Ищу способ трансформировать данные, чтобы во View я мог получить что-то похожее на это.

```php
{
    id: 2,
    name: "Product 2",
    attributes: [
        {
            name: "weight",
            values: [
                "1.3kg"
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "style",
            values: [
                "something nice"
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "color",
            values: [
                "yellow",
                "black",
                "orange"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Имеется возможность вносить любые изменения в проект.

Comment: Зачем вам attribute_id в таблице attribute_product если сами пишите что надо значения только? Вот и замените его на attribute_values_id, и будете не весь список получать а только добавленные атрибуты

Comment: @InDevX Рассматривал этот вариант. Честно сказать, я уже голову сломал. Неужели это настолько сложная задача. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources трансформирует данные, пользуйтесь

Comment: @InDevX Читал. Не понимаю, как Attributed-Value можно трансформировать в Attributed: Value, Value, Value. Можно пример?

Comment: Никак (не совсем, но не надо костылять). Добавьте пример как вы сейчас получаете данные

Comment: @InDevX Все, что у меня есть - я написал. Модели не выложил, потому что, там банально элементарная связь по примерам из документации. Многие-ко-Многим. и Один-ко-Многим. Больше ничего. Чистые модели.

Comment: @ Родион Поляков, Ваша схема позволяет иметь произвольные атрибуты у продуктов, но при этом лишена классификации кроме как по тем же атрибутам. Этим страдает поиск на Озон где в одном запросе выходят лосьоны и кофеварки только потому что они используют родственные атрибуты. Вопрос в том, что действительно (какую гибкость) вы хотите получить. В философии исследований есть положение гласящее что нельзя описать абстракцию изнутри, только поднявшись над ней исследователь получает такую возможность. Это супер-схема. Рабочий пример системные таблицы PostgreSQL - схема позволяющая описывать схемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать создать доп. метод в модели `Product` для трансформации данных.

```
class Product extends Model
{
    // ...

    public function getAttributesData()
    {
        $attributes = $this->attributeValues->groupBy('attribute.name');
        $attributesData = [];

        foreach ($attributes as $attributeName => $values) {
            $attributesData[] = [
                'name' => $attributeName,
                'values' => $values->pluck('name')->toArray()
            ];
        }

        return $attributesData;
    }
}
```

`View`:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $productData = [
        'id' => $product->id,
        'name' => $product->name,
        'attributes' => $product->getAttributesData()
    ];
    // использование $productData для отображения во View
}
```

Можно применить `collection helper` функции `groupBy()`, `map()` и `toArray()` для трансформации данных:

```
$products->map(function ($product) {
    return [
        'id' => $product->id,
        'name' => $product->name,
        'attributes' => $product->attributeValues->groupBy('attribute.name')->map(function ($values, $name) {
            return ['name' => $name, 'values' => $values->pluck('name')->toArray()];
        })->values()->toArray()
    ];
});
```

Comment: Спасибо. Похоже это то, что я искал.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого нужно описать связи в моделях, все нужные таблицы в БД у вас уже есть.
Модель `Product`:

```
...
public function features() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Feature::class)
        ->using(FeatureProduct::class);
}
```

Модель `Feature`:

```
...
public function values() {
    $this->hasMany(FeatureValue::class);
}

// связь с product, если понадобится
public function products() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)
        ->using(FeatureProduct::class);
}
```

После этого можете обращаться ко всем характеристикам товара `$product->features` и ко всем значениям характеристики `$feature->values`, то есть использовать свой цикл, который хотели.

UPD: Теперь понял, тогда как вариант можно ликвидировать таблицу `feature_values`. Вместо этого добавить поле `feature_id` в таблицу `features`. У характеристик `feature_id` будет `null`, а у значений характеристик в этом поле будет `id` характеристики, к которой они относятся. Тогда `$product->features` выведет все значения характеристик с их именами. Если нужно, то при запросе этих характеристик можно будет разбить их по категориям с помощью `keyBy('feature_id')`.

Comment: Я пытаюсь понять, как сделать связь между значением и товаром. Пример: Товар 1 имеет характеристику "Цвет" и значение "Красный". Товар 2 имеет характеристику "Цвет" и значение "Черный". Товар 3 имеет характеристику "Цвет" и значение "Красный" и "Черный". В текущей реализации будут выведены все значения, которые принадлежат данной характеристике.

Comment: @РодионПоляков понял, добавил UPD в ответ

Answer (score -1):

Если вы хотите получить действительно гибкие связи необходимо использовать преимущества ООП. Для этого необходимо подняться на более высокий уровень абстракции и описать таблицу иерархических классов, таблицу его свойств и таблицу значений свойств класса. Каждая фактическая сущность будет наследовать id класса, приобретая коллекцию его атрибутов, значений по умолчанию и возможность осознанного поиска по значению атрибута в контексте иерархии. Это дает гибкость EAV и JSON но при этом таковым по факту не является, так как дает возможность описать и индексировать возможные варианты поиска.